# Adding suffix to variable for every iteration of for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, global-variables

I have searched for similarly worded questions but haven't found one that answers my question.

I have 2 dataframes showing the results on `exam_1` and `exam_2`:

```
exam_1 = pd.DataFrame([['Jim', 87], ['Toby', 44], ['Joe', 71], ['Tom', 59]], columns=['Name', 'Score'])

exam_2 = pd.DataFrame([['Tom', 88], ['Joe', 55], ['Jim', 62], ['Toby', 70]], columns=['Name', 'Score'])
```

I want to iterate through these dataframes such that we:

- remove subjects with `Score` less than 60
- create new dataframes (`J` and `T`) based on the first letter of the subjects name:

```
for df in (exam_1, exam_2):
    
    # Remove subjects with score less than 60
    df = df[df['Score'] >= 60]

    # Dataframe of names starting with 'J' or 'T'
    J = df[df['Name'].str.startswith('J')]
    T = df[df['Name'].str.startswith('T')]
```

**I want to add a suffix to the dataframes `J` and `T` based off the iteration in the for loop**

For example, `exam_1` is the 1st iteration, so the dataframes would be `J_1` and `T_1`.

`exam_2` is the 2nd iteration, so the dataframes would be `J_2` and `T_2`.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html?highlight=globals#globals) ?

```
for idx, df in enumerate((exam_1, exam_2), start=1):
    # Remove subjects with score less than 60
    df = df[df['Score'] >= 60]

    # Dataframe of names starting with 'J' or 'T'
    globals()[f'J_{idx}'] = df[df['Name'].str.startswith('J')]
    globals()[f'T_{idx}'] = df[df['Name'].str.startswith('T')]
```

*NB : This will create the variables (T_1, J_1, T_2 and J_2) as a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` in the global scope.*

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict in your case:

```
J = {}
T = {}

for i, df in enumerate((exam_1, exam_2), 1):
    
    # Remove subjects with score less than 60
    df = df[df['Score'] >= 60]

    # Dataframe of names starting with 'J' or 'T'
    J[i] = df[df['Name'].str.startswith('J')]
    T[i] = df[df['Name'].str.startswith('T')]
```

Output:

```
>>> J[1]
  Name  Score
0  Jim     87
2  Joe     71

>>> J[2]
  Name  Score
2  Jim     62

>>> T[1]  # all scores < 60
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name, Score]
Index: []

>>> T[2]
   Name  Score
0   Tom     88
3  Toby     70
```